# "I am tired and doing my homework." Is it grammatically correct?

Tags: tenses, present-tense, continuous-aspect

Is the sentence in the title absolutely grammatically correct? I recently had an argument with a fellow student, and he said that the sentence is incorrect. I do not think he is right, because I saw numerous examples of such constructions on the Internet, but we were never taught to use such constructions, so I decided to ask here to be sure.

Here are some similar sentences that I just found on the Internet as examples:

(1) I **am tired and thinking** in circles. (From *An Unreasonable Woman: A True Story of Shrimpers, Politicos, Polluters, and the Fight for Seadrift, Texas* by Diane Wilson)

(2) And because I **am tired and doing** what I do not want to be doing, it takes another minute or two before the date sinks in. (From *Man in the Moon: Essays on Fathers and Fatherhood* by Stephanie G'Shwind)

(3) Where were you born? Melbourne, Australia ... What do you want to be when you grow up? I **am grown up and doing** what I want to be doing, Teaching! ([Source](https://ordinary-worlds.com/2018/06/12/tag-29-questions/))

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103223/discussion-on-question-by-mitsuko-i-am-tired-and-doing-my-homework-is-it-gram).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There is nothing *ungrammatical* about this sentence.  It contains a kind of *non-sequitur*.  There are many of these.   For example, *zeugma* involves a kind of *non-sequitur*.  An example of this is as follows.

> He walked into the kitchen wrapped in thought and a bath robe.

Here the zeugma involves the same word (*wrapped*) first metaphorically and then literally.  So the sentence jars and, as a result, can be funny.

This one is not exactly zeugma, but something rather like that.

In the case of your example, you can see the grammaticality of it just by substituting *but* for *and*.

> I am tired but doing my homework.

There is no doubt about the grammar here.  But also, there is a logical connection.  Being tired is associated with not wanting to work or not being able to work.  So if someone says they are tired, we do not expect them to go on and say they are working.  The disconnect is a logical rather than a syntactic one.  There are even contexts in which there is a perfectly good connection between the two statements in your example.

> Mother comes into the daughter's bedroom and says:  "Have you thanked Uncle Edward for that lovely present he gave you?  It's now two weeks ago, you know."  Daughter says "Please, not now, Mother.  I'm tired and doing my homework."

Comment: But how did he walk into the kitchen if it was wrapped in a bathrobe? And just how big is this bathrobe?

Comment: And how _do_ you wrap a kitchen with thought, anyway?

Comment: I can't agree with 'There is no doubt about the grammar here.' Arguably, 'am' filling two different grammatical roles renders the sentence unacceptable. This differs from the different-sense but same-role case, 'He broke the speed limit and the rear brakes'. Wikipedia says that the latter is certainly grammatical (if quirky). But there needs to be substantiating evidence for the grammaticality of OP's example (I'm not saying that it **is** unacceptable).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I can agree that the case is arguable, and that yours is a legitimate argument.  I disagree only with the word “unacceptable”.  You, in turn, are right to challenge my denial of doubt.  I overstated my case which should be that this is a grey area, as I think my example illustrates.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Or, conversely, how small is his kitchen?

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but if I heard a student say "He walked into the kitchen wrapped in thought and a bath robe.", I would assume they are confusing 'wrapped' and 'rapt', which sound very similar. He walked into the kitchen rapt in thought, and wrapped in a bath robe.

Comment: @SamRueby: "very similar" is an understatement: at least on the segmental level, the two words are homophones. Having said that, there may be fine phonetic details that distinguish the two. For example, there are studies that suggest that differences in frequency of use bring about durational differences to the effect that _wrapped_, which is much more frequent than _rapt_, will be pronounced shorter than _rapt_. However, we're talking about a few milliseconds here, a difference that most listeners will not pick even if they listen carefully.

Comment: As a native speaker I find nothing odd with eliding the second "I am", especially not in speech. "I am tired and [I am] doing my homework". It's odd if nothing has established a contextual connection between "tired" and "doing my homework". It might be implicit. It could be made explicit, as in  "I am tired and **still** doing my homework"

Comment: @SamRueby: except that "rapt in thought" is kind of nonsensical, while "wrapped in thought" is a common expression...

Comment: @Martha - Interesting- I would say the opposite! Just one example: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/rapt "Jill stared at them blankly, rapt in thought."

Comment: @SamRueby: hm, this might be worth a question in its own right. A quick search found people arguing for both "wrapped" and "rapt", as well as their love-child "wrapt".

Comment: @Marthaª I also noticed, and enjoyed, the love-child.

Answer (score 37):

Strictly speaking, the title sentence is grammatical, but it sounds unidiomatic because there's no connection between the two predicates. To give some similar examples,

> I am raising money and running for president

sounds fine, but

> I am lifting weights and running for president

sounds funny. Similarly,

> I am tired and thinking in circles

sounds fine — because being tired can make you think in circles — but

> I am tired and doing my homework

sounds a little bit funny.

In fact, this is true in general — if we want to connect two completely different things, we generally tend to leave out fewer repeated words than if we're connecting similar things. An example using nouns rather than verbs is:

> I inherited her house and garden.

That sentence sounds fine, but you probably want to add an extra *her* in

> I inherited her house and **her** rhinoceros.

So to make the original sentence idiomatic, you should say

> I am tired and **am** doing my homework.

However, as John Lawler suggests in the comments,

> I'm tired and **I'm** doing my homework

is even more idiomatic, because people generally contract *I am*.

Comment: It comes of trying to write an essay on a rhinoceros.

Comment: The real problem is that saying _I am_ is unusual. Most English speakers would say _I'm_, which is one less unstressed syllable at the beginning of the sentence (always a good thing), and also means that automatic conjunction reduction is always available: _I'm tired and doing my homework_ is grammatical and normal (though strange -- one looks forward to the next utterance, perhaps _How do you **think** I feel?_). And if you happen to want to repeat _I'm_ in the next clause, you're at liberty to: _I'm tired and I'm doing my homework_ is also fine.

Comment: @JohnLawler: If you add *"how do you think I feel?"* you've just connected *tired* and *doing my homework*, so it becomes idiomatic. Do you think *"I inherited her house and rhinoceros"* is idiomatic? To me, it sounds much better with a second *her*.

Comment: Well, maybe it does with a second possessive. But maybe not; depends on what effect you want, and how well you like her rhinoceros, among other things.

Comment: I disagree that your example sounds better with an extra "her" and that OP's example sounds better with an extra "am". They sound the same both ways to me: a little strange out of context, but not wrong exactly.

Comment: Arguably, 'am' filling two different grammatical roles renders the sentence unacceptable. This differs from the different-sense but same-role case, _He broke the speed limit and the rear brakes_.

Comment: This is also a case where "but" should replace "and".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The real difficulty in writing an essay on a rhinoceros is handing it in without it wandering away or damaging any property.

Comment: "I am lifting weights and running for president" is also a "garden path sentence" - after "I am lifting weights and running" you expect the sentence to continue with something about exercise, as in "I am lifting weights and running for my exercise routine"

Comment: Sort of implicit here but worth stating clearly: *I inherited her house and rhinoceros* carries an implication of a relationship between houses and rhinoceroses, sort of a natural pair. *I inherited her horse and buggy.* *I gave her some of my peanut butter and jelly.* Psychologically, both elements are treated as one unit.

Answer (score 11):

As with each other answer so far, I’ll confirm that the title sentence is perfectly grammatical. There is no real ambiguity or doubt on that score. In contrast to other answers, though, I find nothing odd, funny-sounding, or unidiomatic about the title sentence. I do not consider it a non sequitur.

In the example sentence, “I am tired and thinking in circles,” being tired directly influences the thinking in circles, because fatigue can cause difficulty thinking through things. This is one way in which clauses can be paired with *and* that makes sense. But it is not the only way.

In the title sentence, rather than “being tired” causing the doing of homework, it modifies the expressed experience. Doing homework while tired is a worse experience than either separately. It suggests, perhaps, that the author is overworked (or not budgeting their time correctly), because the best thing to do when tired is rest, and the best time to do homework is when you are well-rested. The combination here emphasizes that the speaker is *not* operating under those ideal circumstances.

It is perfectly reasonable to want to connect these two thoughts with *and* in order to achieve precisely that understanding. I don’t feel there is any particular need to repeat *am* here, or *I am* or *I’m*. You certainly could, it isn’t wrong to do so, but I don’t think there’s any pressure on the sentence suggesting that the author **should** do so. I don’t think the repetition or lack thereof significantly affects the understanding or flow of the sentence. Likewise, using *but* as the conjunction instead of *and* is definitely an option, but I don’t see it as a **superior** option. Nor do I see *I’m* as inherently more natural than *I am* for this usage. I can easily imagine a native speaker using any or all of these options in just about any permutation.

Comment: It sounds quirky as a standalone sentence. You've suggested one possible dequirkifying context (after say "You should have seen what I had to do at work today – it's so difficult"; I suggested another (after say "You should come out to the cinema this evening") (heaping reasons not to). Doubtless justifying context can be engineered for most surface non-sequiturs (I tried to come up with a difficult one).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I simply do not agree. I don’t think it sounds quirky as a standalone sentence at all—I think the sentence all by itself already suggests a context. I could easily see it as a response to something as banal as “how are you doing?” “I am tired and doing homework,” i.e. clearly sub-optimal, enough said.

Comment: We're using 'standalone' differently! I'll substitute 'lacking **any** other context'; I don't mean just 'as a single utterance, though possibly in a dialogue'. Sadly, the former is usually what we are given on ELU.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That still really doesn’t change anything for me. Totally out of the blue, I would still have no surprise at the construction of the sentence. It would just be a gripe—which is something people really do just say out of the blue.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with it, especially in colloquial English. Among friends,

> Friend: Let's go out to the bar.
> Me: I am tired and doing my homework.
>
> [I can't go out.] I am tired and [, besides, I am] doing my homework.

*I have multiple reasons reinforcing why I can't go out*

But also, I suppose it could be used the next morning...

> Friend: Sorry I convinced you to go out last night.
> Me: I am tired and doing my homework.
>
> [I really didn't appreciate that.] I am tired and doing my homework [, and it's all your fault!]

*I have all these things to do and I'm tired and miserable because of you*

So it really depends, but it certainly can convey a clear message with some context.

Answer (score 1):

It’s grammatically acceptable, but a pedantic purist about writing might complain that it isn’t “parallel structure”—one part uses an “-ing” and the other doesn’t.

Comment: In other words, a Pist might get pist.